# DOMXPath Query To Extract Specific li Element

Tags: php, jquery, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to extract a list element based on its child's content. The li has an anchor tag with a title of 'something something' (space included).

Example:

```
<li><a href="#" title="something something"></a></li>
```

What would the query look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve an element with its attribute, use this XPath query:

```
/html/body/li/a[@title='something something']
```

That will get any `a` tag with a `title` attribute with a value of `something something` that's a child of a `li` tag (that's inside `html` and `body` tag, it's better/faster if you know the full structure before hand).

```
<?php
$html = '<li><a href="#" title="something something">test</a></li>';
$html .= '<li><a href="#" title="something something2">test2</a></li>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$lis = $xpath->query("/html/body/li/a[@title='something something']");
foreach ($lis as $li) {
    var_dump($li->nodeValue);
}
```

**Result**

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trello/up.php:9:string 'test' (length=4)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/n5Iqk)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks like what I was looking for. However, I  forgot to mention that the list items are enclosed in a <ul> list. Essentially, I am trying to find the list element with the mentioned attributes, then delete it. Is that even possible? Or Should I find a different approach?

Comment: How about `/html/body/ul/li/a[@title='something something']`?